# Is there a way to dense_rank() over every row within a date range?

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, dense-rank

I'm trying to get a count of unique items in a column given an ID number and where the date is within the last 12 months. I need to iterate this over each row in my table.

I am using a combination of dense_rank() and (Over partition by to calculate the count of unique items, but I haven't been able to add in the date filter successfully. The results I see so far are showing count of distinct Unique_Code for each row with the same ID regardless of the date.

```
select ID, 
       Unique_Code, 
       Transaction_Date,  
       DATEADD(Month, -12, Transaction_Date) as L12M,
       dense_rank() over (partition by ID order by Transaction_Date, Unique_Code) as [Unique_Count]
            from (select *, (case when datediff(day, lag(Transaction_Date,1,Transaction_Date) over (partition by Unique_Code order by ID), Transaction_Date)
             <= 1 
                      then 1 else 2 
                 end) as grp
      from datatable1)
```

I expect the results to show a count of unique items from the unique_code column for the id in the row and where previous entries within the same ID are with the transaction date and the transaction date - 12 months. Right now I am seeing a count of unique items from the unique_code column from each entry with the same ID regardless of the date range.

[image: Table of expected results]

Comment: Stuff like this (Windowing functions) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the feedback. I'm using sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have your source data to test, however, I've added an extra column to yours below:

```
select
    ID
,   Unique_Code
,   Transaction_Date
,   DATEADD(Month, -12, Transaction_Date) as L12M
,   dense_rank() over (partition by ID order by Transaction_Date, Unique_Code) as [Unique_Count]
,   rank() over (partition by Transaction_Date order by ID) NewUniqueCount
from (select *, (case   when datediff(day, lag(Transaction_Date,1,Transaction_Date) over (partition by Unique_Code order by ID), Transaction_Date) <= 1 
                        then 1 else 2 end) as grp from datatable1)
```

Let me know if it works? - It should work.